# Spring Data Rest projection for Embedded Entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

Lets assume I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class Registration {

    @ManyToOne
    private Student student;
    //getters, setters
}

@Entity
public class Student {

    private String id;
    private String userName;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    //getters, setters
}

@Projection(name="minimal", types = {Registration.class, Student.class})
public interface RegistrationProjection {

    String getUserName();
    Student getStudent();

}
```

I'm trying to create the following JSON representation, So when I use `http://localhost:8080/api/registrations?projection=minimal` I dont need all the user data to come along:

```
{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/registrations{?page,size,sort,projection}",
    }
  },
  "_embedded": {
    "registrations": [
      {
        "student": {
          "userName": "user1"
        }
      }
    ],
    "_links": {
      "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/registrations/1{?projection}",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However the Projection I have created I get an exception(it works without the getUserName() statement. Obviously I have defined the interface in the wrong way...but which is the correct way to do something like this?

EDIT: Exception is the following

```
Invalid property &#39;userName&#39; of bean class [com.test.Registration]: 
Could not find field for property during fallback access! (through reference chain: org.springframework.hateoas.PagedResources[&quot;_embedded&quot;]
-&gt;java.util.UnmodifiableMap[&quot;registrations&quot;]-&gt;java.util.ArrayList[0]-&gt;org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.[&quot;content&quot;]
-&gt;$Proxy119[&quot;userName&quot;])</div></body></html>
```

Comment: Might help if you share which exception you got?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As exception said `userName` is not a member of `Registration` entity. That why it failed. But I think you already understand that.

First at all if you just want to expose its projection for `Registration` you should first change the following line:

```
@Projection(name="minimal", types = {Registration.class, Student.class})
```

By setting `types = {Registration.class, Student.class}` you asked Spring Data Rest to apply projection on `Registration.class` and `Student.class`. And that can cause some issue because depending of the type you should not have the same member/methods. In practice `types` must share a common ancestor.

Otherwise for the main problem you should try [virtual projections](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.hidden-data) the following thing (I didn't try on your sample but it should work, I hope):

```
@Projection(name="minimal", types = {Registration.class})
public interface RegistrationProjection {

    @Value("#{target.getStudent().getUserName()}")
    String getUserName();
}
```

I don't know if you are familiar with [SPeL](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) but the previous code just create a `getUserName` like `this.getStudent().getUserName()` because `target` is bound on the instance object (see documentation).

Comment: You seem to have knowledge about projections. Might be an odd question but do you know if it's possible to add projections to a POST of PATCH request without writing a custom controller. Our API is generated by spring.

Comment: @user1758777 unfortunately I'm not using Spring data rest since few years, so I can't help you but I don't think is simply possible to do projection only for POST or PATCH. I advice you to open a new stack question or ask question into Spring data rest Gitter